# htaccess "Order Deny,Allow"

Tags: .htaccess

I am using an **htaccess** file to deny access to all the files except `index.php`... earlier, I used the below code to do that...

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All

<Files "index.php">
   Order Deny,Allow
   allow from all
</Files>
```

Then, I notice that for `http://www.domain.com/`, I am getting a 403 error, means ***forbidden***... where `http://www.domain.com/index.php` is returning http status 200, means completely ok... to solve this problem I add the below code...

```
<Files ".">
    Order Deny,Allow
    allow from all
</Files>
```

And the following codes are working great for me... Now I detect that for `http://www.domain.com` ***(no slash at the end of the address)*** it's returning a 403 error... I have tried some codes... none of them worked for me... do anyone know the solution of my problem...??